# Any way to improve sending push notification quickly using cloud function and fcm or some alternative?

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a Android Chat App and for sending a push notifications for the chat i have deployed a Cloud Function to which is sending notification through Firebase Cloud Messaging. But there's a quite delay in receiving notifications. Is there any alternative for send notification quickly or improving it?

The code for my cloud function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.sendUserMessageNotification = functions.firestore.document("MessagesCollection/{messageChannel}/Messages/{messageId}").onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const document = snap.data();
    const message = document.message;
    const toUserId = document.toUserId;
    const fromUserId = document.fromUserId;
    const fromUserName = document.fromUserName;
    const isAudioMessage = document.audioMessage;

    db.collection("TokenCollection").doc(toUserId).get().then(document => {

        if(document.exists) {

            var tokenDocument = document.data();
            var payload;
    
            if (isAudioMessage) {
    
                payload = {
                    data: {
                        "title": "Message Recieved",
                        "body" : "Voice Message from " + fromUserName,
                        "type": "Message",                
                    }
                };

            } else {

                payload = {
                    data: {
                        "title": "Message Recieved",
                        "body": "Text Message from " + fromUserName, 
                        "type": "Message"
                    }
                };

            }
    
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenDocument.deviceToken, payload).then(response => {
    
                console.log("Message Sent Successfully");
    
            });

        }

    });
});
```

***I'm attaching an image to my cloud function log too maybe it's helpful***

[image: Cloud Function Log]

Comment: You can used one signal alternative of FCM

Comment: you can use postman and manually create a push notification and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Abdul how will postman help in Chat app (Android application)?

Comment: you just want to generate a push notification, so for testing purposes, you can create one from there, like a REST API.

Comment: @Abdul it's not for testing purpose sorry. i'm working on real time chat app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to last execution visible in the logs it seems to be matter of "cold start".

From the log I can see that previous executions have been performed an hour earlier, so I suppose that the execution environment is often initialized from scratch.

You can read few words about it in [Firebase functions Tips & tricks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips) article.

Comment: I have seen that link already. Yes it seem to be matter of "cold start". But this trade of cold start is not very good for a calling and chat app!.

Comment: But this is only when you are use the function after longer period of time. If you are planing Chat App I suppose this will be used massively so this should not be a problem.